# Spring Custom Repository JpaEntityInformation

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have problems to create a custom repository, the code is running but Intellij shows a autowire error for the JpaEntityInformation.

```
Could not autowire. No beans of 'JpaEntityInformation<T, ?>' type found.
```

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface ExtendedRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> 
  extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {
 
    public List<T> findByName(String name);
}
```

```
public class ExtendedRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable>
  extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> implements ExtendedRepository<T, ID> {
    

    public ExtendedRepositoryImpl(JpaEntityInformation<T, ?> 
      entityInformation, EntityManager entityManager) {
        super(entityInformation, entityManager);
    }
}
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "org.test.repository", 
  repositoryBaseClass = ExtendedRepositoryImpl.class)
public class ExtendedConfig {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
JpaEntityInformation<T, ID> entityInformation
```

instead of

```
JpaEntityInformation<T, ?> entityInformation
```

Also you must add `@NoRepositoryBean` to `class ExtendedRepositoryImpl` as well